# Vim-LaTeX with latexmk closes .tex at compilation

Tags: latexmk, vim-latex

**Problem**

When I compile a .tex document with \ll and there are no changes, I get a short prompt and then get back to my document. However when there are changes, I get two other files presented and after closing them I get back to the command prompt as the original document is closed.

P.S.: The Vim-LaTeX documentation mentions a "cwindow" being opened but my search for that yielded no relevant results.

**Details**

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
[...]
Output written on paper.pdf (4 pages, 404964 bytes).
Transcript written on paper.log.
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'paper.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'paper.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [...]
Latexmk: All targets (paper.pdf) are up-to-date

Betätigen Sie die EINGABETASTE oder geben Sie einen Befehl ein
```

When I hit <kbd>return</kbd> as requested, I am presented with `fontenc.sty` and after closing that with `cleverref.sty`:

```
|| (./cleveref.sty)
|| ))
|| (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
paper.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/aer/m/it' undefined
paper.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/aer/bx/n' undefined
paper.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/aett/m/n' undefined
|| [4] (./paper.aux)
paper.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

After I close that, there is no other open file anymore and I am back at the command prompt.

**Context**

The relevant part of my .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -pdf $*'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
```

I use vim 7.4 with Vim-LaTeX (latexsuite 1.8.23, AUR package vim-latexsuite-git 20130127.789-1) and latexmk 4.39 on Arch Linux 3.15.8-1-ARCH.

Comment: That is not the contents of cleverref.sty; it looks just like normal messages that LaTeX / latexmk outputs during compilation. Are you sure you're not closing the buffer yourself by trying to get rid of those messages?

Comment: I am closing them using `:q`, am I supposed to close them differently?

Comment: I think you just have to start typing as usual… try with a simple shell command, e.g. `:!ls`. On my Vim it says "Press ENTER or type command to continue". The other possibility I see is that you could be getting a quickfix window (`:h quickfix`).

Comment: It is indeed a quickfix window that I could close with `:ccl` now, thanks! However there is also a log view which gets opened at the same time.

Comment: @DamienPollet Typing as usual doesn't help, it just writes in the other file that was opened.